# Find records in SQL Server 2008 R2

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

Please find below image for make understanding my issues. I have a table as shown below picture. I need to get only highlighted (yellow) records. What is the best method to find these records?

[image]

Comment: Can you describe why those yellow rows should be chosen, and not the others?

Comment: Select * from table where color = 'yellow'

Comment: this is the RFID punching records, card type 1 is start punch and type 2 is stop punch, so i want one start and very next stop data.

Comment: @shihabvengara Could you describe the logic to why the rows are yellow in your question (usind [edit]) as well, so it is not just in comments? Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

In SQL Server 2012+, you can use the `lead()` and `lag()` functions.  However, this is not available in SQL Server 2008.  Here is a method using `outer apply`:

```
select t.*
from t outer apply
     (select top 1 tprev.*
      from t tprev
      on tprev.time < t.time
      order by tprev.time desc
     ) tprev outer apply
     (select top 1 tnext.*
      from t tnext
      on tnext.time > t.time
      order by tnext.time asc
     )
where (t.cardtype = 1 and tnext.cardtype = 2) or
      (t.cardtype = 2 and tprev.cardtype = 1);
```

With your sample data, it would also be possible to use self joins on the `id` column.  This seems unsafe, though, because there could be gaps in that columns values.

Comment: O.O that complex query :D

Answer (score 0):

Havent tried this, but I think it should work. First, make a view of the table in your question, with the rownumber included as one column:

```
CREATE VIEW v AS
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY id) AS rownum,
  id,
  time,
  card,
  card_type
FROM table
```

Then, you can get all the rows of type 1 followed by a row of type 2 like this:

```
SELECT
  a.id,
  -- And so on...
FROM v AS a
JOIN v AS b ON b.rownum = a.rownum + 1
WHERE a.card_type = 1 AND b.card_type = 2
```

And all the rows of type 2 preceded by a row of type 1 like this:

```
SELECT
  b.id,
  -- And so on...
FROM v AS b
JOIN v AS a ON b.rownum = a.rownum + 1
WHERE a.card_type = 1 AND b.card_type = 2
```

To get them both in the same set of results, you can just use `UNION ALL`. Technically, you don't need the view. You could use nested selects instead, but since you will need to query the table four times it might be nice to have it as a view.

Also, if the ID is continous (it goes 1, 2, 3 without any gaps), you don't need the rownum and can just use the ID instead.

Answer (score -1):

here is a code you can run in sql server

```
 select * from Table_name where id in (1,2,6,7,195,160,164,165)
```

Comment: :) i want to find out based on card type and sequence of the records.

Comment: Perhaps you could write an answer that works even for general data, i.e. without specifying those id values...?